# Blink imageView for few seconds

Tags: android, animation, imageview, splash-screen, duration

In my android application, I have a splash screen which blinks the logo of the app for 3 seconds and then start the login activity.
Here is my code:

```
imgView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            imgView.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    }, 3000);
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashscreenActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But the image blinks infinitely. How to stop blinking after 3 seconds? I referred some posts but I could not get an exact answer.

Comment: I think it's because of the `setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE)` line. Check [Animation.setRepeatCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatCount(int)) description.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to a certain value?

Comment: Also a simplistic `BlinkerView` could do the trick - see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299715/2102748 - the only thing to take care of is to stop blinking on your own. That you can do by posting a message to the handler, like others suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can try this**

```
      final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
      animation.setDuration(1000);
      animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
      animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
      animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
      imgView.startAnimation(animation);

      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              animation .cancel();
              Intent intent = new Intent(SplashscreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);

          }
      }, 3000);
```

You can use **imgView.clearAnimation()** instead of **animation.cancel();**

I hope this will help you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
animation.setRepeatCount(1);
```

instead of

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

with this in your code

```
 animation.setRepeatCount(1);
```